# GParted Change Partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, mbr

Hey, I had a Linux and Windows Installation. Now my Windows installation got corrupted, (was getting a lot of BSODs and was unable to debug) so I thought of reinstallation and when I tried that, things went wrong and now I'm unable to boot.

What I did is:

1. I remove the Linux partition using GParted.
2. Deleted my C partition (wanted to increase it)
3. So, created a new partition

And then I went installing Windows XP, but when the first phase of installation completed (the moment when it restarts), after rebooting, I get this error:

```
Disk error
Press any key to restart
```

Then, I remembered that I had GRUB installed (for dual booting), so I went to Windows XP's Recovery Console and hit this command:

```
fixmbr
```

It wrote the new MBR and when I restarted, same error.

Now I don't know whats the cause can you please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is the C: Partition set at the active partition (also know as the boot partition)?

You can have a single active partition on your disk.  This must be a primary partition and it is the partition your PC will boot from.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a live cd to boot to linux and use gparted to completely wipe the drive and flag it for boot making sure to format to fat32 or ntfs  Once you have done that load up the XP install disc and you should be able to create your partition and boot off of it.  If you don't have access to any bootalbe linux distros with gparted then try the recovery console and run fixboot and chkdsk.  I did the same thing to my laptop except with Vista.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing to a SATA disk did you remember to do the F6 and install additional drivers for the SATA controller?